# Count Split across Shifts

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, query, split

I have a table which registers orders with a PlanStartTime and PlanEndTime. The customer has three shifts in a day starting from 7 AM - 3 PM, 3 PM - 11 PM, 11 PM - 7 AM (next day)

Say an order is planned from 17-Mar-20 8 AM to 17-Mar-20 9 AM and counts of items to be produced is 10, then my first shift count for the work order is 10

```
E.g

PO#     StartDate           EndDate             Count
--------------------------------------------------------
A1      17-Mar-20 8:00      17-Mar-20 9:00      10
--------------------------------------------------------

Expected Results
--------------------------------------------------
Date            Shift       Items to be produced
--------------------------------------------------
17-Mar-20       1           10
```

My Current Problem Statement is in case the work order is to execute across days how can i have the counts distributed across days per shift

```
Problem Statement

PO#      StartDate           EndDate         Count
--------------------------------------------------------
A1      17-Mar-20 8:00      19-Mar-20 9:00      490
--------------------------------------------------------

Expected Results
--------------------------------------------------
Date            Shift       Items to be produced
--------------------------------------------------
17-Mar-20       1           70
17-Mar-20       2           80
17-Mar-20       3           80
18-Mar-20       1           80
18-Mar-20       2           80
18-Mar-20       3           80
19-Mar-20       1           20
```

Note Shift 1 stands for 7 AM to 3 PM 
Shift 2 stands for 3 PM to 11 PM 
Shift 3 stands for 11PM to 7 AM (next day)

The count for the work order needs to be equally distributed across different shifts. The start date to end date duration may vary from 1 hr to max 7 days.

Comment: How do we know the maximum production per shift? Is it 10 per hour?

Comment: trying to distribute the total count equally among the hours and the shift. So in this case if the total count is 490, then each hour has 10 (considering 17 Mar 8 AM to 19 Mar 9 AM is 49 hours). So if the total count was 735, then it would be 15 per hour, hence counts in Shifts which completely come under the window will have a value of 120.
In the above question you may read "Items to be produced" as "Counts per shift"